# BST implementation in java giving errors

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to implement a simple BST and then print out the elements in order. I seem to be getting an erroneous output and even running the debugger, can't really understand what's going wrong. This is my implementation of the BST with the `add` and `inorder` methods.

```
public class BST {
    private Node root;

    private class Node{
        int data;
        Node left;
        Node right;

        public Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    public BST(int item){
        root = new Node(item);
    }

    public void add(int item){
        root = add(item, root);
    }

    private Node add(int item, Node curr){

        if(curr == null){
            curr = new Node(item);
            return curr;
        }
        if(item < curr.data) curr.left = add(item, curr.left);
        if(item > curr.data) curr.right = add(item, curr.left);
        return curr;

    }
    public void inorder(){

        inorder(root);
    }

    private void inorder(Node curr){
        if(curr == null) return;
        inorder(curr.left);
        System.out.print(curr.data + " ");
        inorder(curr.right);
    }
```

This is the calling client.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BST bst = new BST(12);
        //bst.add(12);
        bst.add(7);
        bst.add(16);
        bst.add(3);
        bst.add(9);
        bst.add(13);
        bst.add(19);
        bst.inorder();
        //bst.printLevelByLevel();
    }
}
```

This is the output that I'm getting.

```
3 19 7 3 19 12 3 19 7 3 19 
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can't seem to understand why it's reading the same data multiple times. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please check your typo on the line of `if(item > curr.data)`

Comment: Got it, sorry silly one.

Comment: Unbelievable, have been banging my head on the debugger the whole morning. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Welcome. Typically it's best to debug by reading the code out loud when you can't find it by stepping through lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error exists in your `add()` method.

Minor error here:

```
if (item < curr.data) curr.left = add(item, curr.left);
if (item > curr.data) curr.right = add(item, curr.left);
```

should really be:

```
if (item < curr.data) curr.left = add(item, curr.left);
if (item > curr.data) curr.right = add(item, curr.right);
```

Also, I see another potential problem. You should handle the case where the value you are trying to insert equals the value of the current node. So the condition should be:

```
if(item <= curr.data) curr.left = add(item, curr.left);
```

Otherwise, you never recurse and the new node is never added.

Hope this helps!